# Windows Phone project in an universal app solution cannot have admob control

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm creating an app using the universal app template from visual studio 2013 update 2 and I'm trying to add Admob SDK. However, when I try to compile even before adding the adView control to a page I receive an error saying that this kind of project cannot have an adcontrol.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As for now AdMob library contains only Silverlight components. So it is not compatible with WinRT and Windows Phone 8.1 apps. The only alternative for now is Microsoft's pubCenter, which is limited to list of countries.

Also you can use AdDuplex - it is not exactly for earning but for promoting your app.